# Google Cloud Build - how to do a build/deploy to Firebase with a stateful container that "spins down" to 0 (like cloud run)

Tags: firebase, bitbucket, google-cloud-build

We have most, but not all of our build artifacts into a Git repo (Bitbucket).

Our current build looks like this, and takes 30+ minutes to build/deploy to Firebase, we would like to reduce the time to build.

We are not using Google Cloud Build at the moment, but before heading down that path, I want to find out if that would even be fruitful.

We have all of the code cloned from the git repo (Bitbucket), to a GCE VM.

And then 1 TB of static data is then copied into a directory under the git repo area, artifacts that are needed for the deploy.

We do not want to check in that 1TB of data into the git repo, it is from a 3rd party, it is rarely updated, and would be too heavy of a directory to pull into developer environments on their IDE's, it is pointless to do so.

We launch a build script on the GCE VM to build the code, and deploy to Firebase (bash script), it takes about 30 minutes.

We want the builds to go faster, and possible to use cloud build.

With this:

1. a git repo
2. external files that need to remain in a stateful container, not copied over each time, due to the time it would take

how do we create a stateful container that would only require a git update (pull origin master), and then to fire off a build/deploy to Firebase?

We want to avoid ingress traffic to the Firebase deploy using external build services where the 1TB of data that remains the same each and every time is sent to Firebase, where we would be billed.

Cloud Run containers are not stateful.  GCE VM's are stateful, but it requires that we keep them up and going 24x7x365, so that any developer anywhere can run a build, and that may take only 30 minutes out of any day, and we don't know when that will be, so leaving it up 24x7x365 is mostly wasteful.

We want to avoid building a stateless container where the code is checked out fresh each and every time, a git pull origin master will do, and to have to copy the 1TB of artifacts into the container each and every time taking time.

We just want to do:

1. `git pull origin master`
2. Fire off the build as the next step in the script
3. spin down the container, have it save it's state for the next build, minimizing time, each and every time, saving the previous 'git pull origin master' updated artifacts, and preserving the 1TB files we copied to the container.

---

The ideal situation would be to have a container that is stateful, that spins down when not in use, and "spins up", or is made active for use when we need to do a build.

It would retain the previous git update (git pull origin master), and would retain all artifacts outside the git repo that we copy over.  We also need shell access to the container (ssh, scp) etc.

A stateful 'Cloud Run' option would be ideal, but I don't know of such a thing (stateful containers with GCP that we can run and only be billed for runtime/compute time)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a VM for this. Add a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript). In it

- git pull origin master
- Fire off the build as the next step in the script
- Add this line which stop your compute

```
gcloud compute instances stop $(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id) --zone=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"  http://metadata.google.internal/compu
teMetadata/v1/instance/zone)
```

By the way, each time that you start your VM, it will apply the startup script and shutdown automatically. You keep your persistent disk, and thus your 1TB data, and you pay few because of automatic stop.

If you have to wait an external build. 2 solutions:

- Either you set a sleep timer and shutdown after in the startup script
- Or customize [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) -> At the end of your build, publish a message in PubSub, which trigger a function which will stop your instance.

**EDITED** to reply to comments

Here again, 2 solutions:

- You can create a custom role with only the permission required. You can see all compute role [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/#rest-resource-v1instances). If you provide an access to the console, I recommend list (to view the VMs), start and stop. Else, only start and/or stop if you write a script.
- You can create a private function or Cloud Run. Assign a service account as  identity to this, with enough role to start the VM (*even if there is more permission as required -> it's not a good practice. Prefer the least privilege with custom role*) and grant the role `function.invoker` or `run.invoker` to the user (depend if you use Function or Cloud Run) for allowing it to call this private endpoint and start the VM without right on the VM (only the right to perform an HTTP call).

Comment: This looks great, and I believe it will move us closer to what we need to do.

One additional problem we have is starting the VM.

We have a distributed team of full time staff/employees and contractors in different countries, w/ different hours.

GCP/GCE does not have fine grained permissions to allow a single person or group to start a VM and nothing more.  The permissions to start a VM are grouped with many many other permissions that we do not want to give out,

therefore the VM has to be started by staff, at all hours of the day when there is a request made.

Comment: therefore the VM has to be started by staff, and sometimes the EU contractors need for the VM to be up in the early AM in the US (normal working hours their time).

So we need these contractors to be able to have the VM on, or be able to turn it on whenever they want, and we have not found a solution for this just yet.

Comment: so the next question is how do contractors start the VM, and be given no other permissions on the VM, except for starting it (the other permissions that are bundled with this, with Google's solution gives too many editing rights - delete VM, create new VM's, etc within the same project).  We need the same instant startup solution when a build is kicked off, as the shutdown solution.